# Can I kill my page with one mistake in my service worker?

Tags: service-worker

earlier I deployed a new version of my page, installing a service worker which should only cache an offline page on install and redirect to this cached offline page if the service worker fails to fetch the document because he is offline.

Now something did not work as expected and sometime the service worker would show the offline page although he shouldn't. So I panicked because I couldn't find the problem and deployed a new version which should unregister all service worker. I hoped that everything would work again for everybody.

But then, when I thought about those problems I was shocked, because I realized how dangerous service workers might be, which leads to my question, which I couldn't find anywhere in the world wide web. So maybe someone has an answer for me:

**If I happen to cache a page (for example an offline page) but make the mistake to return this cached offline page not only when my fetch fails, but for every request, what would happen?? Would I then have killed my entire page?**

As I see things the service worker would intercept every request to the server and the user would only see this offline page. Which is cached. So I cannot do anything to unregister the service worker? Because the request would never reach my server or any page which I could modify?

Can you confirm this thesis? Or proof it wrong?

I have a very bad feeling about that.

Thanks for your help to fully understand how dangerous this really is.

Regards

Comment: You can. You can kill your website by changing so many things, not just the service worker.  Can you describe the exact problem you are having in details and the error messages you see (if any) in the console?

Comment: Hi. I don't have any error message because it's just a hypothetical question. I mean I can unregister a service worker on the clients browser as long as I can send a response to the client. But when a broken service worker intercepts every request and responds with some cached data (for EVERY request), I'll never get the chance to send a customized response (which unregisters the broken sw) to the client, will I? So will this broken sw remain installed forever in the clients browser? Is there a lifespan for it? Or do I still have a chance to fix this mess?

Answer (score 0):

Yes.
You could build something that removes/kills a part of any website you created.
And then perhaps build something to make that website work without the pieces you intentionally removed.

It's a most unusual use case.
You probably need to build and test something to see if it works as you expect.